# DNN site running slow in dot net nuke version - 9.4.1

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9, dnn9

I have recently upgraded my website to the dot net nuke version- 9.4.1 but here getting performance issue, the website runs slow. I have searched for this and applied the performance configuration inside the server setting and also did the cache configuration at the page level. 
I have minified the files(Js and CSS) and have updated the setting value inside the host setting table.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check the DNN Scheduler to see if there are any active jobs that are taking longer than they should.  For example, if the Site Crawler scheduler is constantly running then you should check the files in the Portals folders to make sure all of the files located in the Portals folder should actually be there. The crawler is rebuilding the index and if you have a lot of files it could take hours to complete.  If the files should be there, disable the crawler scheduler and then run during your slowest time of the day (1:00 AM?).  I ran into this problem on a server that had hundreds of thousands of documents in the portals folder.  Ended up solving it by running the crawler between 1:00 AM and 5:00 AM for a few days until it indexed all of the files.   Once the files are indexed it will only have to index changed and new files; so it should just be a burden the first time it runs.

Another possible cause are exceptions.  If your site is throwing a large amount of exceptions it will slow down your site.  The handling of the exceptions and then the logging of them (to the DNN EventLog table in the database and the Log4Net files) can be brutal if your site is constantly throwing exceptions.  If your site is also running in DEBUG mode the performance hit is multiplied by at least 30 times due to .Net collection all of the additional information about the exception while running in debug mode. That will be brutal to your sites performance.

Check the server logs to see how often IIS is recycling the application pool for your DNN site. If it's occurring often then that is also a sign of a large amount of exceptions being thrown if you are using the default IIS application pool settings.  By default, IIS will recycle your application pool if too many exceptions are thrown within a short period of time.  If you also have the option set to bring up a new instance of your site and run it side by side before IIS terminates the existing instance while your site is throwing exceptions that can cause a bottleneck and will cripple performance.  For this situation, I usually disable IIS from recycling the application pool if too many exceptions are thrown within a short period of time.  That may not be the best option for you but if you are on top of the exceptions being thrown on the site then you can disable that and let IIS run instances side by side after an app recycle (this is nice to have when you recycle during active periods so that all existing traffic completes with the old instance and all new traffic is sent to the new instance.  Once all traffic is hitting the new instance of your site IIS will terminate the older instance.)

If none of the above help, run SQL Profiler on your database to see if there is any extreme database activities going on.  Also check for any db locks.

There are a lot of possible causes that can slow down DNN.  The best way to find out what is going on is to run a profiler on the server (RedGate Ants profiler or Telerik (Progress) Just Trace).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause of the slow performance was that the Cache was disabled. I've changed under Configuration > Settings > Server Settings > Performance as shown below and the web started running fast like thunder:

[image]